# Apple MacBook Pro M1 , Scanner not opening

Tags: macbook-pro, scanning, apple-silicon, canon

I have recently added Canon TS3100 series printer on my MacBook Pro M1. When I am trying to launch the Scanner, nothing happens and I had to fall back to other devices for initiating the scan.

I have also tried removing and adding the printer again, but no luck so far. Has anyone faced this issue? Any help here is really appreciated.

Comment: Latest drivers? https://th.canon/en/support/0100891104/7 [though there's no mention of macOS 11 or M1]

Comment: Other than having the latest drivers have you tried Image Capture?

Comment: Yes I have the latest drivers and Image capture works fine but not sure if I can use it for scanning from a printer.